# Understand linked list that hold large numbers

Tags: c, unix

I'm currently trying to understand how linked lists work with large integers. Can someone show me a code that allows the user to enter two HUGE positive integers and outputs the sum. I want to see how the linked lists are able to hold these large of numbers.

Sorry if this is a noobie question.

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/add-two-numbers-represented-by-linked-lists/

Comment: a linked list doesn't care about the objects it holds. It's just an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

A linked list is just a container, it doesn't really care what goes inside of it as long as the object is uniform in size across all instances of that object.

The way that a bigint usually gets away with this is every bigint object actually has its own dynamic storage referenced inside its class. This means that an instance of a bigint never changes size because each instance only allocates 1 pointer (4 or 8 bytes) to some other container for the internals of bigint (usually an arraylist or similar).